# No se puede convertir un int a struct en c++

Tags: c++

Tengo un problema con una función que el catedrático nos dio, esta él la realizó pero al momento de compilarla en Borland me muestra el error "Cannot convert 'int' to 'NodoAvl', siendo NodoAvl el nombre del struct. Adjunto el código de la función.

**función:**

```
NodoAvl* InsertarAvl(NodoAvl *raiz, int dato, bool &hc){
    NodoAvl *n1=NULL;<br>
    if (raiz == NULL){
            raiz = new NodoAvl (dato);  **Error cannont convert 'int' to 'strcut'**
            hc = true;
    }else{
            if (dato < raiz->Info){
                    NodoAvl *iz;
                    iz = InsertarAvl(raiz->Izq, dato, hc);
                    raiz->Izq=iz;
                    // regreso por los nodos del camino de búsqueda
                    if (hc){ // siempre se comprueba si creció en altura                      // decrementa el FE por aumentar la altura de rama izquierda
                            switch (raiz->FE){
                                  case 1: // tenía +1 y creció su izquierda
                                        raiz->FE=0;
                                        hc = false; // árbol deja de crecer
                                        break;
                                  case 0: // tenía 0 y creció su izquierda
                                        raiz->FE=-1; //árbol sigue creciendo
                                        break;
                                  case -1: //aplicar rotación a la izquierda
                                        n1 = raiz->Izq;
                                        if (n1->FE == -1)
                                        raiz = RotacionII(raiz, n1);
                                           else
                                           raiz = RotacionID(raiz, n1);
                                           hc = false; 
                            }
                    }
            }else{ 
                    if (dato > raiz->Info){
                        NodoAvl *dr;
                        dr = InsertarAvl(raiz->Der, dato, hc);
                        raiz->Der = dr;
                        // regreso por los nodos del camino de búsqueda
                        if (hc){ // siempre se comprueba si creció en altura
                        //incrementa el FE por aumentar la altura de rama izquierda
                        switch (raiz->FE){
                          case 1: // aplicar rotación a la derecha
                              n1 = raiz->Der;
                              if (n1->FE == 1)
                              raiz = RotacionDD(raiz, n1);
                              else
                              raiz = RotacionDI(raiz,n1);
                              hc = false; 
                              break;
                          case 0: // tenía 0 y creció su derecha
                              raiz->FE = 1; // árbol sigue creciendo
                              break;
                          case -1: // tenía -1 y creció su derecha
                              raiz->FE = 0;
                              hc = false; // árbol deja de crecer
                                    }
                            }
                    }else
                            throw "No puede haber claves repetidas " ;
            }        
    }
    return raiz;
}
```

Comment: ¿puedes incluir el código del constructor del struct NodoAvl?, si tiene, y que propiedades tiene declaradas.

Comment: Esta es la estructura  struct NodoAvl{
 NodoArbol *Izq;
 NodoArbol *Der;
 char Info;
 int FE;
};

Answer (score 2):

Como ya han señalado [rnd](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/25/rnd) y [eferion](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/6918/2742), se trata de un problema de ausencia de constructor; el error mostrado en un caso similar por CLang es ligeramente más esclarecedor:

```
error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'NodoAvl'
auto na = new NodoAvl(666);
              ^       ~~~
note: candidate constructor (the implicit copy constructor) not viable: no known conversion from 'int' to 'const NodoAvl' for 1st argument
struct NodoAvl
       ^
note: candidate constructor (the implicit move constructor) not viable: no known conversion from 'int' to 'NodoAvl' for 1st argument
struct NodoAvl
       ^
note: candidate constructor (the implicit default constructor) not viable: requires 0 arguments, but 1 was provided
```

Puedes verlo [aquí](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/QUnoSDW6HYbfiUVR).

Sin embargo, si tu `NodoAvl` es (o fuese) un agregado, podrías usar la inicialización de agregado para resolver el problema:

```
raiz = new NodoAvl {dato};
```

Nótese que uso llaves en lugar de paréntesis; de esta manera no llamo al constructor con `int` (del que carece) si no al constructor como agregado.

Por otro lado, tienes un problema adicional con tu código, no sé cómo usas la función `InsertarAvl` pero en la línea en que asignas valor al puntero `raiz`, que recibes como parámetro de entrada, no estás modificando el puntero recibido si no una copia, así pues, usando la función así:

```
NodoAvl *n = NULL;
bool hc;
InsertarAvl(n, 0xFabada, hc);
```

El puntero `n` seguiría siendo `NULL` después de la llamada a `InsertarAvl`; si quieres modificar el puntero, debes pasarlo como puntero a puntero o como referencia a puntero:

```
NodoAvl* InsertarAvl(NodoAvl **raiz, int dato, bool &hc){
    NodoAvl *n1=NULL;
    if (raiz == NULL){
            *raiz = new NodoAvl (dato);
            hc = true;
    }
    ...
    ...

NodoAvl* InsertarAvl(NodoAvl *&raiz, int dato, bool &hc){
    NodoAvl *n1=NULL;
    if (raiz == NULL){
            raiz = new NodoAvl (dato);
            hc = true;
    }
    ...
    ...
```

Yo prefiero referencia a puntero.

Answer (score 1):

```
raiz = new NodoAvl (dato);
```

En esa línea el programa está intentando llamar al constructor

```
NodoAvl(int);
```

Si dicho constructor no existe entonces el compilador intenta una conversión implícita. Si resulta que el compilador es incapaz de encontrar la conversión implícita la compilación finalizará con error.

En tu caso todo apunta a que te falta por implementar el constructor correspondiente en `NodoAvl`.

Si este no es el problema tendrás que poner más información, como te indica @rnd.

Un saludo.